# Comparar dos listas en python

Tags: python

Mostrar el top 10 de los Super Héroes con mayor altura, considerando que deben tener pelo y raza asignada. La información que se muestra es el nombre, género, color de ojos, raza, color de pelo, altura y casa de
publicación.

Me dan un **archivo.csv** con esa info.
PARTE DE LA INFO DEL ARCHIVO.

```
cod,name,gender,eyecolor,race,haircolor,height,publisher,skincolor,alignment,weight
0,A-Bomb,Male,yellow,Human,No Hair,203.0,Marvel Comics,-,good,441.0
1,Abe Sapien,Male,blue,Icthyo Sapien,No Hair,191.0,Dark Horse Comics,blue,good,65.0
2,Abin Sur,Male,blue,Ungaran,No Hair,185.0,DC Comics,red,good,90.0
3,Abomination,Male,green,Human / Radiation,No Hair,203.0,Marvel Comics,-,bad,441.0
4,Abraxas,Male,blue,Cosmic Entity,Black,-99.0,Marvel Comics,-,bad,-99.0
5,Absorbing Man,Male,blue,Human,No Hair,193.0,Marvel Comics,-,bad,122.0
6,Adam Monroe,Male,blue,-,Blond,-99.0,NBC - Heroes,-,good,-99.0
7,Adam Strange,Male,blue,Human,Blond,185.0,DC Comics,-,good,88.0
```

A la hora de comparar las dos listas, una con la **info** y otra con la **altura**, me da error y no se qué pueda ser.

Esto es lo que llevo de código.

```
lista_info = []
top_10 = []

archivos = open("prueba2.csv", "r")
for linea in archivos:
    info = [str(i) for i in linea.split(',')]
    if info[4] != "-":
        if info[5] != '-' and info[5] != "No Hair":
            lista_info.append(info)
    if info[6] != 'height':
        if info[6] not in lista_info:
            if float(info[6]) > float('279.0'):
                top_10.append(info[6])
                top_10.sort(reverse=True)

for i in lista_info:
    for c in top_10:
        if i ==lista_info[6]:
            print(i)
```

Comment: ¿Con cual info te dan el .csv?, revisa que tu pregunta contenga toda la informacion necesaria para que te puedan ayudar.

Comment: adjunta el error de la consola

Answer (score 0):

La comparación lo que hace es comparar la altura con todo el arreglo, de la lista_info, creo que lo que querías hacer era comparar con `c==lista_info[6]` y en este caso `c` contiene las alturas que guardaste en los if de arriba, pero probando ese cambio no funciona para los valores que mostraste en el csv.

Esta es otra forma que puedes hacer para tu requisito:

Primero guardas en la lista_info todos los héroes que cumplan los requerimientos.

```
lista_info = []
top_10 = []

archivos = open("heroes.csv", "r")
for linea in archivos:
    info = [str(i) for i in linea.split(',')]
    if info[4] != "-":
        if info[5] != '-' and info[5] != "No Hair" and info[6] != 'height':
            lista_info.append(info)
```

Ordenas respecto al valor de la altura que en este caso es la posición 6.

```
lista_info.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[6]), reverse=True)
```

Imprimes el top 10, o puedes guardarlo en la otra lista en caso de que ocupes hacer algo mas con la información. (Agregue unos condicionales para evitar desbordamientos en caso de que no haya héroes suficientes).

```
for i in range(10):
    if(i >= len(lista_info)):
        break

    print(lista_info[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

## **CAUSA DEL ERROR DEL CODIGO**

Hola Sakura, el error que arroja tu codigo es porque en la linea final de tu archivo csv se encuentra solo un caracter de escape "\n", el cual al ser recibido por la linea `info = [str(i) for i in linea.split(',')]` en su correspondiente iteracion del for, genera una lista con un solo elemento `info = ["\n"]`, variable que inmediatamente despues, en la condicion del if, accedes a su elemento de posicion 4 `if info[4] != "-":` para saber si en este hay un guion. Debido a que la lista de la variable info contiene solo un elemento, al indexar la posicion 4, python identifica el error de sintaxis IndexError.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si deseas comprobar la existencia de esa ultima linea con el caracter \n te dejo el siguiente codigo:

```
archivo = open("prueba2.csv", "r")
print(archivo)
lineas = []
for linea in archivo:
    lineas.append( linea.split(","))
archivo.close()    
    
for linea in lineas:
    print(linea)
```

---

## **Solucion**

La falencia de tu codigo reside en no presentar condiciones para filtrar lineas no deseadas, tales como las que solo contienen "\n".
Para ignorar este contenido, simplemente se recurre a otra condicion bastante sencilla `if len(info) == 10:`. De esta forma puedes NO procesar las lineas que no cumplen la condicion de poseer 10 elementos separados por coma.

El codigo quedaria:

```
lista_info = []
top_10 = []

archivos = open("prueba2.csv", "r")
# print(archivos)
for linea in archivos:
    # print(linea)
    info = linea.strip().split(",")
    # print(info)
    if len(info) == 10:
        if info[4] != "-":
            if info[5] != '-' and info[5] != "No Hair":
                lista_info.append(info)
        if info[6] != 'height':
            if info[6] not in lista_info:
                if float(info[6]) > float('279.0'):
                    top_10.append(info[6])
                    top_10.sort(reverse=True)

for i in lista_info:
    for c in top_10:
        if i ==lista_info[6]:
            print(i)
```

### **Simplificaciones.**

Algunas secciones de tu codigo se pueden simplificar para que sean mas faciles de leer  y comprender para el programador. Otras son redundantes. Por lo que mi solucion se compone de dos etapas separadas:

1. almacenamiento de datos
2. procesamiento de altura

Redundancias:
La siguiente linea `info = [str(i) for i in linea.split(',')]` es redundante usar este for comprimido ya que todo esto se realiza con tan solo con los metodo `split("\n")` y `strip()` por lo que se sustituye por la sentencia `info = linea.strip().split(",")`

antigua
`info = [str(i) for i in linea.split(',')]`
nueva
`info = linea.strip().split(",")`

Ademas, es bueno separar funcionalidades en python, para mantener el codigo lo mas facil de leer y entender, por lo que separare el filtrado de datos del acceso de datos al csv.

El almacenamiento de datos queda de la siguiente forma:

```
archivo = open("prueba2.csv", "r")
print(archivo)
lineas = []
for linea in archivo:
    lineas.append( linea.split(","))
archivo.close()
```

! recuerda siempre cerrar los archivos cuando los uses, de otra forma a la siguiente ejecucion te arrojara error porque el archivo sigue en uso.

Entonces, la informacion del csv queda almacenada en una lista de listas en la variable `lineas`.

### **Procesamiento de la informacion**

Para identificar a los 10 heroes mas altos que si tengan informacion de raza y pelo se procede a identificar tal informacion en su respectiva posicion en cada linea, cumpliendo la condicion, se almacena en una lista la altura del jugador.

Se comienza recorriendo la lista contenida en lineas `for linea in lineas:`, luego, se consulta que la linea tenga 10 datos y la presencia de la informacion de raza y pelo a traves de la condicion `if len(linea)==11 and linea[4] != "-" and linea[5] != "No Hair":`. si se cumple la condicion, se agrega la altura linea[6] a la lista de alturas, de otra forma, se sigue al siguiente.

```
alturas = []
for linea in lineas:
    condicion = len(linea)==10 and linea[4] != "-" and linea[5] != "No Hair"
    if condicion :
       alturas.append(linea[6])
```

Finalmente, para identificar a las 10 mayores alturas se realizan dos cosas:

1. recurres al metodo sort() de la clase lista, el cual ordena de mayor
   a menor tus datos numericos: `alturas.sort()` .
2. indexas una rebanada de los ultimos 10 elementos de la lista
   contenida en alturas `print(alturas[-10:])` .

El codigo del procesamiento es:

```
alturas.sort()
print(alturas[-10:])
```

Con esto se termina tu ejercicio. adjunto el codigo final en un archivo para que no se generen errores por copiado.

---

## **CODIGO FINAL**

```
######################### ALMACENAMIENTO DE DATOS ##########################
archivo = open("prueba2.csv", "r")
print(archivo)
lineas = []
for linea in archivo:
    lineas.append( linea.split(","))
archivo.close()   
########################## FILTRADO DE ALTURAS ##############################
alturas = []
for linea in lineas:
    # print(linea)
    condicion = len(linea)==11 and linea[4] != "-" and linea[5] != "No Hair" and linea[6] != "height"
    if condicion :
       alturas.append(linea[6])
############################# MAYORES ALTURAS ##########################
alturas.sort()
print(alturas)
```

**LINK DEL PROGRAMA**

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1byMKhjhFHRvC5vDOqWxKNC3ZsfEWSJSP/view?usp=sharing

**Precauciones**

El codigo arrojara error si el archivo no se encuentra en la misma carpeta que el programa
El codigo arrojara error si se indica un nombre equivocado del archivo csv.
El codigo arrojara error si se indica una extension distinta a .csv